How does an image translate into feature embeddings?
How does an image of a cat or dog translates into a numerical matrix. Take VGG16 using the matrix output of the final layer pre classification layer. What does the matrix output represent ?? How is it related to the image ?! How does a clustering algorithm like KNN use it to know that there is a dog or cat in this image and group them?!

Did you try out model interpretation like gradcam?

@AIFahim yes and it works. I just don’t understand how !! So the output vector at the very end of the CNN , do they still possess spatial reference to the pixel location in the initial image ?! My understanding is that the positional index of the output vector represents a recognized complex shape and value represents confidence it exists in the image input.

Your question is a little hard to follow but I'll try my best to answer.
Images can be converted into 3-dimensional matrices, storing the red, green, and blue numerical values for each pixel as its own separate value. The result is effectively 3 matrices, of the same size as the original image, stacked on top of each other that individually represent the strength of R/G/B colors at each point in the image.
The output of VGG16 pre-readout or 'classification' layer is basically just a single vector that, conceptually, contains all of the information necessary to classify the image. This makes sense, because clearly all of the information the model needs to classify the image must be condensed into that final embedding.
When ML people say "feature extraction", this is more of an abstract term. It's not like a feature (ex. a dog's nose) is literally translated into a numerical value in the feature embedding, but rather that the relevant information in the image is somehow embedded.
With regard to KNN, personally I'm not as experienced in clustering as I would like. However, the basic idea of clustering is that, for an unlabeled dataset (ex. a bunch of images of cats and dogs that aren't specified as being of cats or dogs), a model can still be put to use by trying to group similar things together. In the case of cats and dogs, there should be some obvious differences visually that the model will notice, without necessarily "knowing" that the images it's looking at are of different animals (after all, what the heck is an animal to an ML model?). Once the model has produced these groupings, it's up to the practitioner (you!) to decide what the labels are. As a human being, you'll have a pretty easy time going "oh, this group is a bunch of pictures of dogs".
If you think about it, most learning in the real world is unsupervised/clustering. When you were a baby, you could probably tell the difference between a rhinoceros and a turtle long before you learned that one was called a "rhinoceros" and the other a "turtle".

“ but rather that the relevant information in the image is somehow embedded.” this somehow is what I am asking about. How exactly ?!
Otherwise , a very elaborate answer , thank you.

The information in the embedding (aka a vector) is not something you're supposed to be able to interpret as a human. The reason why all the relevant information ends up being somehow encoded in that vector is simply a matter of the way we chose to train the model. We forced the model to make a prediction by applying a series of matrix operations to our input that eventually gives us the prediction we asked for, and therefore the model is required to figure out a way (that makes sense to the model) to "extract" the features it needs to make our prediction.
